# NPM publish to scoped private package without having to login

Tags: node.js, npm

I am trying to find a way to be able to publish a private npm package without having to login every time to npm. I guess I can achieve that by using an `.npmrc` file in the root of the project, but I cant find more details on how exactly to achieve that, how to generate the npmrc with the right config.

**Any idea? Any help highly appreciated.**

Answer (score 3):

I think to publish your private `npm-package` you need to login to `npm` once for the first time. After the first successful login, the `npm` creates a `_authToken` in your `.npmrc` file. Until and unless your `.npmrc` file contains this `_authToken` with the appropriate value, you don't need to login again to `npm` to publish next `npm-package`.

Best of my knowledge, Unless you remove that `_authToken` Or delete the `.npmrc` file Or manually logged out from `npm` I am sure you don't have to login again to publish `npm package`.

Hope this will help you :)

Comment: Note that the `.npmrc` on a typical installation will be saved to `~/` (``C:\Users\name\`` in Windows)

Comment: Thanks @ Patrick Roberts, Another way to find and open the same using `gedit ~/.npmrc` command in Ubuntu.